# Move subsite with running workflows to new site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am looking to essentially promote a subsite up to its own site collection on a different content database, but all data and currently running workflows need to be preserved. Currently, I have a SharePoint 2013 environment with a single web application, single site collection, and then several subsites. I now need to move these subsites to their own site collection, but I have several lists with 2013 designer workflows currently running. The status/stage of these workflows need to be preserved. Is this possible? I have seen a few people mention backup/restore and then delete what isn't needed. But does this preserve running workflows or does this only copy workflows over to the new site collection?

Comment: Yes refering to this question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/78456/77968

Answer (score 0):

Workflows designed with SharePoint Designer will keep running as the same status.

VS Workflows will show as completed.

Answer (score 0):

As you are running sharepoint 2013 workflows their status will be not preserved. SP 2013 WF is decoupled from Shaerpoint and it is separate product. You could try a scope restore procedure (REF:https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC356)

In my opinion best option you have is to migrate the site and then re-create the status of the workflows (you might need to rewrite them a bit to allow for this kind of functionality)